# average degree of a node

Tags: python-3.x, graph, networkx

The question is: Write a Python function that accepts a NetworkX graph and a node name and returns the average degree of that node's neighbors. Use this function to compute this quan-tity for every node in the OpenFlights US network and take the average. Does the Friendship Paradox hold here (i.e. is the average degree of nearest neighbors greater than the average node degree)?

````
def averagedegree(G,node)
    for node in G.neighbors(node)
    2 * V.number_of_edges(node) / V.number_of_nodes(node) ```

and then I want to return a dict of the average degree of the neighbors BUT the average number of nodes and number of edges BOTH accept no arguments
````

Comment: Perhaps it would help to read the documentation on [number_of_edges](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/classes/generated/networkx.Graph.number_of_edges.html), [number_of_nodes](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/classes/generated/networkx.Graph.number_of_nodes.html) and [neighbors](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/classes/generated/networkx.Graph.neighbors.html)

Comment: As for the second question, you need to compute the average degree in the whole graph. You probably have a formula for that in your course. Hint: you don't need to compute the individual degrees and average them; you can calculate the average degree just by knowing the number of edges and the number of nodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The average degree of the node's neighbours is the sum of the degrees of each neighbour, divided by the number of neighbours. The number of neighbours of a node is exactly its degree.

The degree of a node `u` in a networkx Graph `G` is `G.degree(u)`.

In python, the sum can easily be obtained with builtin function `sum`.

Relevant documentation:

- [Graph.degree](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/classes/generated/networkx.Graph.degree.html);
- [Graph.neighbors](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/classes/generated/networkx.Graph.neighbors.html).

```py
def average_degree(G, u):
    return sum(G.degree(v) for v in G.neighbors(u)) / G.degree(u)
```

Note that this function will raise `ZeroDivisionError` if `u` has no neighbours.

Testing with a custom graph:

```py
from networkx import Graph

G = Graph()
G.add_edges_from([(0, 2), (0, 7), (2, 1), (2, 9), (2, 8), (1, 8), (1, 3), (9, 6), (9, 4), (9, 7), (8, 7), (8, 5), (8, 6), (7, 5), (7, 6)])

avg_degrees_dict = { u: average_degree(G,u) for u in G.nodes }

print(avg_degrees_dict)
# {0: 4.5,
#  1: 3.3333333333333335,
#  2: 3.5,
#  3: 3.0,
#  4: 4.0,
#  5: 5.0,
#  6: 4.666666666666667,
#  7: 3.2,
#  8: 3.4,
#  9: 3.25}
```

Comment: this helped me a lot thanks. But now if I want to search for the neighbors for node 'ANC' I get different neighbors(as expected) but the same value (not expected). The same goes for other nodes ` def
 average_degree(G, u):
    return sum(G.degree(v) for v in G.neighbors(u)) / G.degree(u)`

avg_degrees_dict = { u: average_degree(V,'ANC') for u in V.nodes}

print(avg_degrees_dict)```

Comment: @codepythonuser3222 I don't understand the issue. What's node 'ANC'? Why is it not expected to get "the same value"?